# dns-nameserver entries are ignored after 127.x.x.x

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolvconf

I'm trying to configure a static eth0 in a 1404 vps (lxc container). My interface config is

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 192.168.10.10
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1 192.168.10.10
dns-search example.com
```

I want first lookup to be localhost and second to be another dns on my lan.

It would appear that the entries in `dns-nameservers` are IGNORED after any entry beginning with `127`. The `resolv.conf` only contains entries up to and including the first 127 entry.

If I don't use 127 then it works fine and `resolv.conf` gets all expected entries. For example the below results in two entries:

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 192.168.10.10
```

So, whatever reads those `dns-` stanzas from the interface config (I have been unable to determine where this happens but have read it's `ifup` that does it) is filtering them for some reason.

My question is why?